# Can we make DataTable sort automatically on a column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that gets filled simultaneously from 7 different functions.There are many columns and one of them is **Price** which is in same format e.g `127,12`

One method is at the end when all the functions are done i sort the `DataTable` and show user the result.

But to avoid the above is there a way i can make it `Sort By Default`  on a column so when the Data is being entered it automatically moves it up and down in rows for the rite position.
Is there a built in function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Price"
```

Columns are sorted is ascending order by default. If you need to sort in descending order:

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Price DESC"
```

You can also sort based on multiple columns:

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Price, Name"
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply.

Comment: Yes it does perfectly , unfortunately i have to wait 10 mins before accepting an answer :)

Comment: can i ask you something regarding the sort?